# How to join spatial data file with geocoded csv file

Tags: r, geocoding, tableau-api, spatial, qgis

I have a polygon spatial file that is used to map school zones in nyc, and a csv containing geocoded property locations with longitude and latitude coordinates. I need to join the two together so that every property that is say within school zone 1 is joined to it along with the other unique columns associated with the two datasets.

I've been able to map the school zone data, and property data by themselves in Tableau and QGIS, but I'm unable to join them together in Tableau as they lack a similar unique identifier and I've been unable to get a spatial join in QGIS to work either. I've also attempted a few things in R converting the spatial file to get it's coordinates without success. I'm willing to use any of the resources listed here or anything else that may be needed.

Comment: Check this old thread out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r

Comment: can you please post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Some example data would be handy too